# JQuery: Why does parent().parent.parent() work but parents(selector) doesnt?

Tags: jquery, parent

I've been working with jQuery and tried to add a class to a parent element that was 3 steps up the DOM tree. I didn't get it to work with "parents('selector')" but with "parent().parent().parent()". 
Could anyone of you help me out and explain why this isn't working?

```js
function activeNav() {
        
        var nav_list_content = $('.nav_list_content');
        var nav_sub_list_content = $('.nav_sub_list_content');
        var CountNavSubListElements = nav_sub_list_content.length;
        var CountNavListElements = nav_list_content.length;
      
        
        
         for(var c = 0; c<CountNavListElements; c++){
             if(nav_list_content.eq(c).attr("href") == window.location.href){
                
                nav_list_content.eq(c).addClass('active_nav_link');
               break;
            }
         }
        
         for(var c = 0; c<CountNavSubListElements; c++){
             if(nav_sub_list_content.eq(c).attr("href") == window.location.href){
                
                nav_sub_list_content.eq(c).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active_nav_link'); /*Does work*/
                
              nav_sub_list_content.eq(c).parents('.nav_list_content').addClass('active_nav_link');  /*Doesn't work*/  
                
               break;
            }
         }
      
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="prime_nav">
            <div id="mobile_menu_button"><a id="mobile_menu_button_content" class="attr">&#9776</a></div> 
            <div id="nav_wrapper">
                <img id="logo" src="Logo.png">
                <ul id="nav_list" class="nos">
                    <li class="nav_list_element"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:50241/index.html" class="nav_list_content attr">Home</a></li><!-- 
                 --><li class="nav_list_element"><a href="#" class="nav_list_content attr">Page</a></li><!--
                 --><li class="nav_list_element">
                        <a href="#" class="nav_list_content attr">Page</a>
                        <ul id="nav_sub_list">
                            <li class="nav_sub_list_element"><a href="http://127.0.0.1:50241/index.html" class="nav_sub_list_content attr">Page</a></li>
                            <li class="nav_sub_list_element"><a href="#" class="nav_sub_list_content attr">Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><!--
                 --><li class="nav_list_element"><a href="#" class="nav_list_content attr">Page</a></li><!--
                 --><li class="nav_list_element"><a href="#" class="nav_list_content attr">Page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
 </nav>
```

I'm sorry for so much code. But I appreciate your help.

Comment: use only `partents()` not with `eq(c)`

Comment: that does't work because i have to select on of the nav_sub_list_content's that are stored in that jQuery Object to get his 3rd parent. I don't want to to it for all of them.

Comment: actually what you want to do

Comment: have you tried `.closest(SELECTOR)`

Comment: @Omi I'm sorry if i missunderstood it, but still your suggestion doesn't work for me

Comment: @WizardCoder I have tried it and it didn't work either

Comment: i doesn't mean that, i mean what you want to achieve, i think you are doing something complex

Comment: @Omi oh I see, sorry

this function is triggered once the page loads. It should check each nav link whether its href is equal to the current path of the website and change it's css class so the link is with a different background color. That way the User can see where he is on the page directly in the navigation bar. Also for the sub-list (dropdown) it should check that as well and since the dropdown is hidden, the parent (the visible nav-element) should get that css class to show the user where he's at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nav_sub_list_content.eq(c).parent().parent().parent()` is selecting the `.nav_list_element` element. You are passing `.nav_list_content` to the `parents()` function, which won't work because that is the class of the element you are tying to find the parent of.

This:

`nav_sub_list_content.eq(c).parents('.nav_list_content').addClass('active_nav_link');`

Should be:

`nav_sub_list_content.eq(c).parents(".nav_list_element").addClass('active_nav_link');`

Comment: Thank's for your help and explanation. That worked perfectly.